# No ruler/protractor/interactive ruler hotkey?

Tags: shortcut

Am I right in my conclusion that there's no ruler/protractor/interactive ruler hotkey?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not, but you could create one easily enough.  In the Toolbar, in the Grease Pencil tab, right-click on the "Ruler/Protractor" button.  From the menu that pops up, choose "Add Shortcut".  Then make it whatever you want, e.g. Ctrl-Alt-R (I don't think that's mapped to anything?).

Comment: Where is it in 2.8+?